# How to temporarily disable browsersync?

Tags: livereload, browser-sync

How can I temporarily disable [browsersync](http://www.browsersync.io/), so that it doesn't inject/modify HTML pages? (For testing and debugging.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a configuration option to do just this, but one hacky workaround is to use [`snippetOptions`](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-snippetOptions) to specify a string that will will never be found in the HTML:

```
snippetOptions: {
  rule: {
    match: /qqqqqqqqq/
  }
}
```

If this string cannot be found in the HTML, the snippet will never be injected, and browsersync will be inert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Yargs to send parameters and enable or disable 'watch' task.

Remember this command line to install required components:
`npm i --save gulp browser-sync yargs runSequence`

On gulpfile.js file:

```
browserSync.init({
    port: 80,
    notify: false,
    cors: true,
    browser: 'chrome',
    open: 'local'
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync'], function (){
    gulp.watch('dev/*.html', browserSync.reload); 
    gulp.watch('dev/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('dev/**/*.css', browserSync.reload); 
});

gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
    var sequence = ['browserSync'];
    if (args.sync){
        sequence.push('watch')
    }

    runSequence(sequence,callback);
});
```

This `if (args.sync)` lines use truthy/falsy searching for `sync` values and enable/disable 'watch' task.

BrowserSync with watch:
`gulp --sync true`

BrowserSync without watch:
`gulp` or `gulp --sync false`